# Yahtzee Application class

Tags: java

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to programming, and I could really use help with an assignment I've been working on. I'm trying to get a yahtzee program working with this expected output (the rolled dice are random)

```
Round 1 
Roll 1: 
5 6 5 5 2 
Which die value do you want to keep? 
5 
Roll 2: 
5 6 5 5 3 
Which die value do you want to keep? 
5 
Roll 3: 
5 1 5 5 5 
Which location would you like to record this round? 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 0 points 
3s: 0 points 
4s: 0 points 
5s: 0 points 
These values are automatically output 
to the console when you call the 
showDice method in the GUI class.  Page 6 of 9
6s: 0 points 
5 
Round 1 complete. 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 0 points 
3s: 0 points 
4s: 0 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 0 points 

Round 2 
Roll 1: 
1 2 4 4 3 
Which die value do you want to keep? 
4 
Roll 2: 
3 4 4 4 6 
Which die value do you want to keep? 
4 
Roll 3: 
4 4 4 4 4 
Which location would you like to record this round? 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 0 points 
3s: 0 points 
4s: 0 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 0 points 
4 
Round 2 complete. 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 0 points 
3s: 0 points 
4s: 20 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 0 points 

Round 3 
Roll 1: 
5 1 4 1 6 
Which die value do you want to keep? 
5 
Roll 2: 
5 2 4 1 3 
Which die value do you want to keep? 
5 
Roll 3: 
5 6 3 1 3 
Which location would you like to record this round? 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 0 points 
3s: 0 points 
4s: 20 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 0 points  Page 7 of 9
5 
There is already a score for location 5. Which location would you like to 
record this round? 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 0 points 
3s: 0 points 
4s: 20 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 0 points 
4 
There is already a score for location 4. Which location would you like to 
record this round? 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 0 points 
3s: 0 points 
4s: 20 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 0 points 
3 
Round 3 complete. 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 0 points 
3s: 6 points 
4s: 20 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 0 points 

Round 4 
Roll 1: 
1 3 2 3 1 
Which die value do you want to keep? 
1 
Roll 2: 
1 2 2 5 1 
Which die value do you want to keep? 
2 
Roll 3: 
2 2 2 2 1 
Which location would you like to record this round? 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 0 points 
3s: 6 points 
4s: 20 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 0 points 
2 
Round 4 complete. 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 8 points 
3s: 6 points 
4s: 20 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 0 points 

The player can choose to 
keep the value 1 after the 
first roll, but choose to 
keep value 2 after the 
second roll. 
If the player attempts to enter a score in 
a location that already has a score, they 
are told the location already has a score 
and are asked again to choose a 
location. They will continue to be 
asked until they enter an empty 
location.  Page 8 of 9
Round 5 
Roll 1: 
4 5 1 5 6 
Which die value do you want to keep? 
6 
Roll 2: 
1 2 5 4 6 
Which die value do you want to keep? 
6 
Roll 3: 
6 1 1 1 6 
Which location would you like to record this round? 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 8 points 
3s: 6 points 
4s: 20 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 0 points 
6 
Round 5 complete. 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 8 points 
3s: 6 points 
4s: 20 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 12 points 

Round 6 
Roll 1: 
1 6 4 3 2 
Which die value do you want to keep? 
1 
Roll 2: 
1 6 6 1 2 
Which die value do you want to keep? 
1 
Roll 3: 
1 5 5 1 6 
Which location would you like to record this round? 
Scores: 
1s: 0 points 
2s: 8 points 
3s: 6 points 
4s: 20 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 12 points 
1 
Round 6 complete. 
Scores: 
1s: 2 points 
2s: 8 points 
3s: 6 points 
4s: 20 points 
5s: 20 points 
6s: 12 points
```

Game over! Your total score is 68

This is the code I have so far

```
  package proj5;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Project5App {

        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            GUI diceTable = new GUI();
            DiceArray dice = new DiceArray(5);
            int[] scoreCard = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0};
            int count = 1;

            for(int j = 1; j < 7; j++)// j: rounds
            {
                System.out.println("Round " + j);
                for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)// i: the rolls 
                {
                    if(i < 3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Roll " + i + ":");
                        dice.roll();
                        diceTable.showDice(dice);
                        System.out.println("Which die value do you want to keep?");
                        int keep = sc.nextInt();
                        dice.keep(keep);
                    }

                    if (i == 3)
                    {   
                        System.out.println("Roll " + i + ":");
                        dice.roll();
                        diceTable.showDice(dice);
                        System.out.println("Which location would you like to record this round?\nScores:");
                        for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++)//k: score card location
                        {
                            if (scoreCard[k] > 0)
                                System.out.println("There is already a score for location " );
                                System.out.println(count + "s: " + scoreCard[k] + " points");
                                count++;
                        }
                        count = 1;
                        int location = sc.nextInt();
                        int sum = dice.calculateTotal(location);
                        System.out.println(location);

                        System.out.println("Round " + j + " complete.");
                        dice.reset();   
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

I'm not too sure on how to get my scorecard to display twice in the round without making 2 loops and I don't know how to get the added dice to display in the scorecard at the end of the round. I just can't figure this one out on my own. Can anyone offer any insight?

Edit: Heres the entire DiceArray class My expected output and what I want it to do is written above.

```
    package proj5;
/**
 * <p>Title: Project 5</p>
 *
 * <p>Description: Creates an array of dice that rolls, keeps and displays the values of each die. </p>
 *
 * @author 
 */

public class DiceArray 
{
    //instance variables
    private int[] dice;
    private boolean[] diceToRoll;

    /**
     * Name: Parameterized Constructor </P>
     * Description: Receives the number of dice, and instantiates both instances variables. </p>
     * @param numDice the number of dice to be used
     */
    public DiceArray(int numDice)
    {
        dice = new int[numDice];
        diceToRoll = new boolean[numDice];

        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
        {   
            dice[i] = -1;
            diceToRoll[i] = true;
        }   
    }

    /**
     * Name: toString method </P>
     * Description: Create and return a string with the values of the dice, and whether or not they are kept. </p>
     * @return a String with the values of the die and whether or not they are true or false
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        String output = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
        {
            output += dice[i] + " ";
        }
        output += "\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
        {   
            if (diceToRoll[i] == true)
                output += "T" + " ";
            else
                output += "F" + " ";
        }

        return output;
    }

    /**
     * Name: roll method </P>
     * Description: Rolls dice based on which ones are set to 'true'. </p>
     */
    public void roll()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
        {   
            if (diceToRoll[i] == true)
                dice[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
        }   
    }

    /**
     * Name: getDice method </P>
     * Description: Return the reference of the array dice. </p>
     * @return the value of the reference of the array.
     */
    public int[] getDice()
    {
        return dice;
    }

    /**
     * Name: reset method </P>
     * Description: Sets all the diceToRoll values to true, allowing them all to be 
     * rolled the next time the roll method is called. </p>
     */
    public void reset()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
            diceToRoll[i] = true;
    }

    /**
     * Name: keep method </P>
     * Description: Will accept an int that indicates which of the dice value that should be kept. </p>
     * @param diceVal the value to be compared to the dice values
     */
    public void keep(int diceVal)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
        {
            if(dice[i] == diceVal)
                diceToRoll[i] = false;
            else
                diceToRoll[i] = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Name: calculateTotal method </P>
     * Description: Will accept an int indicating which of the values to calculate a total for. </p>
     * @param val the value of the dice values to be added together
     * @return an int of the sum of the values
     */ 
    public int calculateTotal(int val)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++)
        {
            if (dice[i] == val)
                sum = sum + val;
        }

        return sum;
    }


}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to post the calculateTotal method? Also, explain what it is doing and what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: you're probably gonna want to show all of the `DiceArray` code too...

Comment: Of course, apologies, I just put it in :)

Comment: I just figured out I didn't have a variable set for the sum, and I just fixed it. Silly me. But my other questions still remain unanswered

Comment: Small thing, but your Java doc is incorrect, if you want to use the html `<p>` tag you must open and close the tag